# Wijimo flex sheet not showing the column - But it shows if the all records have the values

Tags: wijmo

We have a web application, Wijmo flex sheet is used for reporting purposes. One column("AddressLine2") not showing even if the value is in some records. Postgresql(AWS RDS) id our DB and Spring boot is the backend. Actually, I am expecting the column will not shows in the Wijimo report if all values are empty on the corresponding column

Please suggest a solution for this

Comment: is Column binding and key is same?

Comment: We have the same binding name. Also checked the Rest api the value is coming from the Backend.

Comment: wijmo will not show the column if all the values in that column is empty. Would you be able to create a minimal code sandbox to check the issue?